# Expected Indented Block -Python - nested loop

Tags: python, loops

I have this code:

```
import matplotlib


loopski = 1

while loopski == 1:
    ending = 0
    selection1 = input('Hvilket niveau? ')

    if selection1 == 'a':
            selectionA1 = input('Hvilket emne?')
            
    if selection1 == 'b':   
        selection2 = input('Hvilket emne? ')
        if selection2 == 'Linear Algebra':
            selection3 = input('Hvilken formel? ')
        elif selection2 == 'Hovedmenu':
            loopski = 2
            selection3 = 'null'
            
        while (selection3 == 'Linjens Hældning') and (ending != 'N'):
        selection4 = input('Hvilken formel?' )
            if selection4 == '1':
                x1 = int(input('Angiv x1 '))
                y1 = int(input('Angiv y1 '))
                x2 = int(input('Angiv x2 '))
                y2 = int(input('Angiv y2 '))
                    
                a = (x2-x1)/(y2-y1) 
                b = y2 - (a*x2)
                print('Din ligninger er: Y = {}x + {b}'.format(a,b))
            elif selection4 == '2':
                    print('lol')
            elif selection4 == '3':
                    
            
        while (selection3 == 'To-Punkters Hældning') and (ending != 'N') :
            x1 = int(input('Definer x1 '))
            y1 = int(input('Definer y1 '))
            x2 = int(input('Definer x2 '))
            y2 = int(input('definer y2 '))

            aFun = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

            a = aFun

            b = y1 - (a*x1)

            print('Formlen for de to punkter er: {}x + {}'.format(a,b)) 

            ending = input('Tilfreds? Y(es)/N(o) ')

            if ending == 'Y':
                print('Perfekt :)')
                loopski = 2
                break
            elif ending == 'N':
                print('Du vil nu bive bragt tilbage til hovedmenu')
            else:
                print('ugyldigt svar')
                ending = input('Tilfreds? Y/N ')
```

I keep getting the error:

> File "Linear algebra.py", line 37
> while (selection3 == 'To-Punkters Hældning') and (ending != 'N') :
> ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block

What I don't understand is, shouldn't while selection3 == 'To-Punkters Hældning'-loop(I will reffer to this as loop A) be on the same "level" as while selection3 == 'Linjens Hældning'-loop(I will reffer to this as loop B)?

The way I believe this works is, that selection 3 will/won't fulfill the requirements for loop B, and then it will go on to loop A, and if neither of them work, it will return back to the same line asking for the same input?

Comment: The line ```print('lol')``` is indented twice

Comment: `selection4 = input('Hvilken formel?' )` should be indented

Comment: `selection4 = input('Hvilken formel?' )` is not indented at all after the while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work,

```
import matplotlib


loopski = 1

while loopski == 1:
    ending = 0
    selection1 = input('Hvilket niveau? ')

    if selection1 == 'a':
        selectionA1 = input('Hvilket emne?')
            
    if selection1 == 'b':   
        selection2 = input('Hvilket emne? ')
        if selection2 == 'Linear Algebra':
            selection3 = input('Hvilken formel? ')
        elif selection2 == 'Hovedmenu':
            loopski = 2
            selection3 = 'null'
            
        while(selection3 == 'Linjens Hældning' and ending != 'N'):
            selection4 = input('Hvilken formel?' )
            if selection4 == '1':
                x1 = int(input('Angiv x1 '))
                y1 = int(input('Angiv y1 '))
                x2 = int(input('Angiv x2 '))
                y2 = int(input('Angiv y2 '))
                    
                a = (x2-x1)/(y2-y1) 
                b = y2 - (a*x2)
                print('Din ligninger er: Y = {}x + {b}'.format(a,b))
            elif selection4 == '2':
                print('lol')
            elif selection4 == '3':
                print("selection4=3") #replace with your code block/logic here.
        
                    
            
        while(selection3 == 'To-Punkters Hældning' and ending != 'N'):
            x1 = int(input('Definer x1 '))
            y1 = int(input('Definer y1 '))
            x2 = int(input('Definer x2 '))
            y2 = int(input('definer y2 '))

            aFun = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

            a = aFun

            b = y1 - (a*x1)

            print('Formlen for de to punkter er: {}x + {}'.format(a,b)) 

            ending = input('Tilfreds? Y(es)/N(o) ')

            if ending == 'Y':
                print('Perfekt :)')
                loopski = 2
                break
            elif ending == 'N':
                print('Du vil nu bive bragt tilbage til hovedmenu')
            else:
                print('ugyldigt svar')
                ending = input('Tilfreds? Y/N ')
```

The issue is not concerned with indentation(although, there were few indentation issues, which are fixed in the given code), the problem here was with the `elif(selection4==3)` block, which apparently had no statements to be executed(meaning incomplete **while block**). Hence I added a dummy print statement and it's working fine now, replace the print statement with your appropriate logic and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you, your code worked.

But when I tried to add more to it, I got the 

  "File "sas.py", line 60
    ending = 0
             ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)

Press any key to continue . . ."-error

Are you by any chance using spacebar when indenting?

Comment: Did you try using auto-indentation? That should fix the error, also could you please show the addition you made, so that I can help you rectify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import matplotlib


loopski = 1

while loopski == 1:
    ending = 0
    selection1 = input('Hvilket niveau? ')

    if selection1 == 'a':
            selectionA1 = input('Hvilket emne?')
            
    if selection1 == 'b':   
        selection2 = input('Hvilket emne? ')
        if selection2 == 'Linear Algebra':
            selection3 = input('Hvilken formel? ')
        elif selection2 == 'Hovedmenu':
            loopski = 2
            selection3 = 'null'
            
        while (selection3 == 'Linjens Hældning') and (ending != 'N'):
            selection4 = input('Hvilken formel?' )
            if selection4 == '1':
                x1 = int(input('Angiv x1 '))
                y1 = int(input('Angiv y1 '))
                x2 = int(input('Angiv x2 '))
                y2 = int(input('Angiv y2 '))
                    
                a = (x2-x1)/(y2-y1) 
                b = y2 - (a*x2)
                print('Din ligninger er: Y = {}x + {b}'.format(a,b))
            elif selection4 == '2':
                    print('lol')
            elif selection4 == '3':
                    
            
        while (selection3 == 'To-Punkters Hældning') and (ending != 'N') :
            x1 = int(input('Definer x1 '))
            y1 = int(input('Definer y1 '))
            x2 = int(input('Definer x2 '))
            y2 = int(input('definer y2 '))

            aFun = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

            a = aFun

            b = y1 - (a*x1)

            print('Formlen for de to punkter er: {}x + {}'.format(a,b)) 

            ending = input('Tilfreds? Y(es)/N(o) ')

            if ending == 'Y':
                print('Perfekt :)')
                loopski = 2
                break
            elif ending == 'N':
                print('Du vil nu bive bragt tilbage til hovedmenu')
            else:
                print('ugyldigt svar')
                ending = input('Tilfreds? Y/N ')
```

The line directly after the while loop and before the if statement needed to indented once more.

Comment: I tried directly copy + pasting your code, and I got the same error message, I believe you forgot to indent it on your answer.

I indented "selection4 = input('Hvilken formel? ') and got this error message:

"  File "forsoegg2.py", line 22
    selection4 = input('Hvilken formel? ')
                                         ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)

Press any key to continue . . .
"